# how to use awk to get substring either side of a specified position

Tags: regex, awk, sed

I am using awk to get a substring based on a position variable. Imagine:

```
string = "ABC NGC 2345678."
echo $string | awk '{print substr($0,5,8)}'
```

outputs:

```
"NGC 2345"
```

This is all fine, however what if I wanted to extract 8 letters either side of the position 5? Or better still, because only 5 positions exist going backwards, how to I generalise this to get a substring that is "up to 8 positions either side of the position of interest?"

so that the output is

```
"ABC NGC 2345"
```

Thanks.

Comment: What is your expected output?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you may want to have a generic solution, not only for solving your example problem.

take a look this awk one-liner:

```
awk -v i=5 -v o=8 '{d=i-o;s=d>0?d:1;print substr($0,s,2*o+(d<0?d:1))}'
```

You just need to change the `i ( interesting position)` and `o (the offset to each side)`

let's make a test:

```
kent$  str="54321#123456789"                                                                                                                                                

kent$  awk -v i=6 -v o=3 '{d=i-o;s=d>0?d:1;print substr($0,s,2*o+(d<0?d:1))}'<<<$str                                                                                
321#123

kent$  awk -v i=6 -v o=5 '{d=i-o;s=d>0?d:1;print substr($0,s,2*o+(d<0?d:1))}'<<<$str                                                                                
54321#12345

kent$  awk -v i=6 -v o=7 '{d=i-o;s=d>0?d:1;print substr($0,s,2*o+(d<0?d:1))}'<<<$str                                                                                
54321#1234567

kent$  awk -v i=6 -v o=77 '{d=i-o;s=d>0?d:1;print substr($0,s,2*o+(d<0?d:1))}'<<<$str
54321#123456789
```

Comment: This was exactly what I wanted. I appreciate the generic solution

Answer (score 1):

You could use sed here.

```
$ echo "ABC NGC 2345678." | sed 's/^\(.\{4\}..\{0,7\}\).*/\1/'
ABC NGC 2345
```